# Azure Storage Emulator v4.6.0.0 - How to list current tables

Tags: azure-table-storage, azure-storage-emulator

I'm using 4.6.0.0 of the azure storage emulator.  Is there anyway to list the tables currently in the emulator, either through a web browser call, e.g.

```
http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/[some args?]
```

Or at the emulator's cmd line?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you could directly list the tables at the emulator's cmd line.

Note: you should firstly installed the azure cli.You could install it in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli).

Then you could use the azure cli command to list the all the table in the emulator.

You could try below command:

```
azure storage table list --connection-string DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10000/devstoreaccount1;TableEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://127.0.0.1:10001/devstoreaccount1;
```

The result is like below:
[image]

More details about how to use azure cli and storage Emulator, you could refer to below article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator

Comment: Thanks @Brando.  Regarding azure CLI, step one is interesting: "Visit the Python site and download Python for Windows."

Comment: You could also install the azure CLI by using Microsoft Web Platform Installer. You could download it at this link:https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx

Comment: Any update? If you feel my answer is useful /helpful. Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat helpful.  Basically it looks like you cannot list tables in the emulator without using some other software.

Comment: Yes, the emulator is a local azure storage provider it is as same as the azure storage. It doesn't contain the list command. If you want to list the blob, you need send the request to the http://127.0.0.1:10002/devstoreaccount1/[some args?] by using crul or some other software. The azure SDK will automatic send the request if you execute the command.